# Phalcon 3: Validating form data using \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator

Tags: php, validation, phalcon

Since the latest version of Phalcon was released, the examples provided in the documentation do not seem to work correctly.

Firstly, I create a new model with [DevTools](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html) at the command line using `phalcon model User`.

Then, I amend the `validation()` function. My `models\User.php` file:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email as Email;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness as Uniqueness;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\StringLength as StringLength;

class User extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function validation()
    {
        $this->validate(
            new Email(
                array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'message' => 'Please enter a valid email'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->validate(
            new Uniqueness(
                array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'message' => 'Your email is already in use'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->validate(
            new StringLength(
                array(
                    'field' => 'password',
                    'min' => 4,
                    'max' => 30,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password must be at least 4 characters',
                    'maxMessage' => 'Your password must be less than 30 characters'
                )
            )
        );

        if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However, this throws the following error:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Argument 1 passed to Phalcon\Mvc\Model::validate() must implement interface Phalcon\ValidationInterface, instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\app\models\User.php** on line **27**

What does this mean? I believed that `Phalcon\Validation` and `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator` were completely different beasties (the latter providing more functionality)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of Phalcon 3.0 `Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validation` is now deprecated in favor of `Phalcon\Validation`. This was done to reduce the code base, since both of the components were doing similar jobs. Below you can find examples of what needs to be changed.

#### Old way:

```
namespace Invo\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Email as EmailValidator;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Validator\Uniqueness as UniquenessValidator;

class Users extends Model
{
    public function validation()
    {
        $this->validate(
            new EmailValidator(
                [
                    'field' => 'email',
                ]
            )
        );

        $this->validate(
            new UniquenessValidator(
                [
                    'field'   => 'username',
                    'message' => 'Sorry, That username is already taken',
                ]
            )
        );

        if ($this->validationHasFailed() == true) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

#### New way:

```
namespace Invo\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Email as EmailValidator;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness as UniquenessValidator;

class Users extends Model
{
    public function validation()
    {
        $validator = new Validation();

        $validator->add(
            'email', //your field name
            new EmailValidator([
                'model' => $this,
                'message' => 'Please enter a correct email address'
            ])
        );

        $validator->add(
            'username',
            new UniquenessValidator([
                'model' => $this,
                'message' => 'Sorry, That username is already taken',
            ])
        );

        return $this->validate($validator);
    }
}
```

More info and patch notes can be found in [the Blog](https://blog.phalconphp.com/).

Comment: Also keep in mind that `'model' => $this,` is not needed actually.

Comment: @Juri, nice remark have to test it tomorrow. Took the example from the blog.

Comment: Beacause it was written while ago :) And i did some things to make validation better and easier, check class docs here for examples - https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/master/phalcon/validation/validator